# Why is my System.Threading.Task.ContinueWith firing at the wrong time

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to handle exceptions from a System.Threading.Tasks.Task

I haven't used these before, and seem to be misunderstanding how the `ContinueWith` works; thus my `ContinueWith` is firing at the wrong time.

Given the following; `workers` is just a list of my long running processes.

```
......
workers.Add(new Workers.Tests.TestWorker1());
workers.Add(new Workers.Tests.TestWorker2());

// Start all the workers.
workers.ForEach(worker =>
    {
    // worker.Start schedules a timer and calls DoWork in the worker
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(worker.Start); 
    task.ContinueWith(ExceptionHandler, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    task.Start();
    })
.....
```

My handler method is

```
private void ExceptionHandler(System.Threading.Tasks.Task arg1, object arg2)
{
    DebugLogger.Write("uh oh.. it died");
}
```

My `TestWorker`'s are:

```
class TestWorker1 : Worker
    {
        int count = 1;
        public override void DoWork(object timerState)
        {
            DebugLogger.Write(string.Format("{0} ran {1} times", workerName, count));
            count++;
            ScheduleTimer();
        }
    }
```

And

```
class TestWorker2 : Worker
{
    int count = 1;
    public override void DoWork(object timerState)
    {
        DebugLogger.Write(string.Format("{0} ran {1} times", workerName, count));
        count++;

        if (count == 3)
            throw new Exception("I'm going to die....");

        ScheduleTimer();
    }
}
```

`ScheduleTimer()` simply sets an interval for DoWork to be run

**What happens...**

When I debug, all tasks are created and started. As soon as the`DoWork` has called `ScheduleTimer()` for the first time, my ExceptionHandler is hit; as shown in this screenshot - this happens for both workers.

[image]

When the exception is hit in `TestWorker2` the debugger will not move on from there - in that i press continue, hoping to hit my `ExceptionHandler`, and the debugger just keeps throwing the exception.

**What I am hoping to achieve**

I would like my `ExceptionHandler` to only fire when an exception within the running tasks is thrown. I'm finding the only time i get into my `ExceptionHandler` is when it's run, and my actual exception just keeps looping.

What am i missing?

Per comment, here is the code for the main `Worker`

```
public abstract class Worker : IDisposable
    {
        internal string workerName;
        internal Timer scheduler;
        internal DateTime scheduledTime;

        public Worker()
        {
            string t = this.GetType().ToString();
            workerName = t.Substring(t.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).AddSpacesBeforeUppercase(true).Trim();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Set to true when the worker is performing its task, false when its complete
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsCurrentlyProcessing { get; set; }

        public void Start()
        {
            DebugLogger.Write(workerName + "  Started");
            ScheduleTimer();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// default functionality for setting up the timer. 
        /// Typically, the timer will fire in 60  second intervals
        /// Override this method in child classes for different functionality
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void ScheduleTimer()
        {
            scheduler = new Timer(new TimerCallback(DoWork));
            int interval = 60;
            int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[string.Format("{0}{1}", workerName.Replace(" ", ""), "Interval")], out interval);
            scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(interval);
            if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTime)
                scheduledTime = scheduledTime.AddSeconds(interval);

            int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
            scheduler.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        public abstract void DoWork(object timerState);

        public void Stop()
        {
            // kill stuff
            if (scheduler != null)
                scheduler.Dispose();
            DebugLogger.Write(workerName + " stop");
            this.Dispose();
        }

        private bool disposed = false;
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
                if (disposing)
                {
                    // any specific cleanup

                }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does your Worker class look like?

Comment: Code for the worker just added.

Comment: Something to be aware of, your `ContinueWith` will not catch Worker 2's exception when `count == 3` (or any other exceptions raised in `DoWork`), is that what you want to happen?

Comment: oh.... yes, that's what I'm after - figured they would bubble all the way up

Comment: Once you are inside the timer you are nolonger part of the call chain that started the timer. The `Task` will be completed successfully after the `scheduler.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);` line completes and any errors after that point won't be tracked.

Comment: Ok. I believe I understand more now. I can use an event handler to pass up any sort of exception to my parent thread in this case then. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

From your screenshot it appears that `arg2` is your `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` object, that is the biggest clue of what is going wrong. Because you passed in a `Action<Task, Object>` it is using the [`Task.ContinueWith Method (Action<Task, Object>, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139097(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `ContinueWith`, this is causing your continuation options to be passed in as the `state` parameter.

Either change `ExceptionHandler` to

```
private void ExceptionHandler(System.Threading.Tasks.Task arg1)
{
    DebugLogger.Write("uh oh.. it died");
}
```

so you will use the [`Task.ContinueWith(Action<Task>, TaskContinuationOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321576(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, or you can change your call to

```
task.ContinueWith(ExceptionHandler, null, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

so that you will start using the [`Task.ContinueWith(Action<Task, Object>, Object, TaskContinuationOptions)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194741(v=vs.110).aspx) overload.

Comment: Good eye, that's one innocent looking line. Named parameters ftw.

Answer (score 0):

Might be caused by your logging component not supporting multiple concurrent writes.
If it's possible for you, I'd suggest you refactor the code to the `async`/`await` pattern, it will be much more readable.
Let's say you create a list of all the tasks you want to run:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

workers.ForEach(worker => tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => worker.Start())));
```

and then use `await` on the list surrounded by a `try` `catch` block:

```
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    DebugLogger.Write("uh oh.. it died");
}
```

Also, make sure you are not doing any `Thread.Wait(xxx)` calls (or any other `Thread.XXX` calls for that matter) inside `ScheduleTimer()`, because tasks and threads don't play nice together.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My logger is thread safe. I also get the same result if i comment out any calls to the logger. Thanks for the input though :)

Comment: No problem!
Using `async` `await` will make following the flow of execution in your code much easier!

Comment: BTW, If the only purpose of the timer is to the delay the code once, you can changed it to `await Task.Delay(interval)`.